# Rinkeby Ether faucet error

Tags: blockchain, ether, synchronization, rinkeby, faucets

I got funded from the rinkeby faucet but it didn't show up in my wallet. Does anyone have an idea why the sync with the rinkeby blockchain stopped with just 218 remaining?

Comment: A node synchronised in fast mode will not return meaninful information until has finished syncing. You can check your balance in https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/

Answer (score 0):

What client are you using? Geth tends to have these problems with synchronizing with the network, especially when you use a GUI. You can use an online or local version of MEW. On the top right corner of MEW you can select the drop down menu and choose the Rinkeby testnet, and it will allow you to access your funds.

Be careful that you are using ONLY your testnet keystore/private key, as you do not want to expose your real Ether. Also make sure that if you use an online version, look for the green lock. If you're using a local version, verify the signatures if you have them.